# I can't run Java on Terminal

Tags: java, terminal

Help on running Java on Terminal

[image]

I already typed java and the package name, it still couldnt run on Terminal. Why?

Comment: You can't run your class from the src directory. You need to tell java where to find the compiled file.

Comment: @Jamie I don't know what version they're using but from Java 11, you *can* just specify the filename provided its a single file https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Comment: @user16320675 
hi my main.class is in 'out'

Comment: (In the LearnJava directory) `java -cp out com.ziliangpoh.Main`

Answer (score 3):

You are using an IDE that do that for you when you run your application. Press the righ green arrow in the top bar or press `SHIFT+F10` or right click on the file `Main` and then "run".

If you want to use the terminal, first compile it:

```
javac ClassName.java
```

Then run it:

```
java ClassName
```